# How to write a Makefile to compile a simple C program

Tags: c, unix, makefile

Compile the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   printf ("Hello from your first program!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

a)-by using file of type Makefile

b)-the executable will be named Hello

"Please help to do an exercise. I know how to do it in CodeBlocks, but I don't know what Makefile is and how to write it in Linux. I compiled it using command "gcc filename.c" and subsequently "./a.out"  but I still don't understand what the Makefile is. Is it a sort of shell script, an instruction? How would a Makefile for this task exactly look? Thanks in advance :) "

Comment: Have you tried googling for [Makefile tutorial](https://www.google.de/search?q=makfile+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=T7PwUrOHL4Td_AbPooGIAQ)?

Comment: Have you tried [CMake tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)?

Comment: For some reason, low-level programmers DO participate in StackOverflow but think that is not the right place to provide good answers and teach the ones who don't know, only to be cynical and provide links or suggest to read man pages ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @RafaelEyng c++ isn't low-level

Answer (score 25):

This is your simple make file for hello program.

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g
RM      = rm -f


default: all

all: Hello

Hello: Hello.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Hello Hello.c

clean veryclean:
    $(RM) Hello
```

Suppose you have two `makefiles` in one directory named `makefile.m1` and `makefile.m2` and if you want build both make file then please use following commands

```
make -f makefile.m1
make -f makefile.m2
```

or use single `Makefile` that contains:

```
m1:
  make -f makefile.m1

m2:
  make -f makefile.m2
```

and use `make m1` or `make m2`

Now lets clear your doubt about name of make file must not require `Makefile`

You can name makefile whatever you want. suppose i  would  like  to give name `myfirstmakefile.mk`. To use it later you need to tell make what makefile you want. Use -f option for this:

```
make -f myfirstmakefile.mk
```

And again extantion `.mk` is also not manadatory you can use whatever you want but never forgot to use `-f` option.

so may this help make sense to you.

Comment: Thanks very much. ? With what unix shell command did you begin? did you first enter in nano Hello.c (wrote the Hello world program and the typed nano Hello.makefile, or what was your steps from the start?

Comment: I wrote that into a file named `mkmk` using nano and when I typed `make mkmk` it says 1make: nothing to be done by default` but why

Comment: No,In linux just copy above code in new file named `Makefile` and also make `Hello.c` program in same directory where above `Makefile` you put.Now from terminal go to that directory and simply type `make` to build `Hello.c` and `make clean` to clean output.

Comment: I've observed if you name a makefile name other than "Makefile" it doesn't work, what if you need to make two makefiles?

Comment: Nope...not mandatory to give make file name as `Makefile` you can give as you want..let me explain you makefile rules in more details..please see my updated answer.

Comment: what are the first three lines of the Makefile? CC, CFLAGS, RM? What do they do? and default, all are targets? could you pls explain what the each line of the makefile that you have written, does. Thanks

Comment: `CC,CFLAGS,RM` are just makefile variables.You can give name as you want.[This link will help you](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)

Comment: This answer should mention that makefiles require to be tab indented and that copying the receipts in the answer will not preserve that and as such, won't work verbatim.

Answer (score 12):

A *makefile* is a recipe for the `make` utility how to create some file (called a *target*) from some other files (called dependencies) using a set of commands run by the shell. A makefile typically looks like this:

```
target: dependency [...]
        command1
        command2
```

Try running `man make` for details.

Now for your task, really there is no need for a Makefile, since `make` has built-in rules that know how to compile a simple program. All you need to do is place your C source in a file named after the executable name (`Hello`) and with a `.c` extension, i.e. `Hello.c`.

Then a simple

```
$ make Hello
cc     Hello.c   -o Hello
```

does everything. If you want to use gcc instead of cc, you can run

```
$ rm Hello
$ make CC=gcc Hello
gcc     Hello.c   -o Hello
```

If you tell your instructor/teacher/prof that an empty makefile is all you need since you know the built-in rules do the right thing, you'll get some extra credit and maybe your instructor has learnt something new :-) If you are asked for a reference, you could quote the relevant parts of the make manual, or, do it like a pro, quote from the [POSIX Standard for the make utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), section **Default Rules**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to make sure I got it right. First I created a Hello.c using nano and a my source code, then I saved and exited it, and typed (`make Hello`) in terminal console (ofLinux/Unix) and I got (`cc Hello.c -o Hello`) underneath my command. So I guess that cc(is for compile c) and (-o is sth if linking puts executable output in the file output, but what does it actually do/mean in ordinary words(compiles Hello.c and gives an empty output of the Makefile instructions bu default?). But then I run the same command (`make Hello`) and it gave (`make: `Hello' is up to date.`)

Comment: `make` compile your `Hello.c` file and create binary as per your file name.If you again give `make` command then it will look for change in your `Hello.c` file if not found then simply output `Hello is upto date`

Comment: @Zhivago When you run make a second time, it checks if the dependency is younger than the target. If so, it runs the commands. If not, there's nothing to do and make says 'Hello is up-to-date'. It is smart enough to know that if Hello.c did not change, there's no need to compile it. That's the whole point of make: do the minimum work necessary to update a target. If you `touch Hello.c` or `rm Hello` it will recompile.

Comment: @Zhivago The `-o file` option to the compiler names the result file (which defaults to `a.out`. Yes, `cc` is the traditional Unix C compiler name, which on Linux is identical to `gcc`.

Comment: @Jens Could you please tell me what didi you do when you wrote $ make CC=gcc Hello  did you set an argument or a variable

Comment: @Zhivago `$` is a symbol for the prompt. So that line runs the `make` command with two arguments, `CC=gcc` to set a *make* variable and `Hello` as the target to build.

Answer (score 9):

before going for makefile you have to know what's it and why we need it

What is Makefile?

Makefile is a script written in a certain prescribed syntax which helps to build the target output (normally, one or more executables) from source files by compilation and linking. In simple words, makefile will compile your source code in simple & fast way.
Why we need Makefile?

=> Large projects can contain multiple source files which are dependent in one another or arranged in hierarchical manner for example, in order to compile file A, you have to first compile B; in order to compile B, you have to first compile C; and so on.

=> Make is a solution to these problems. It can be used to compile whole project in well arranged manner and generate your target according to your make rule(which we will discuss later) by entering single command that is make.

=> An important feature is that when a project is recompiled after a few changes, it will recompile only those files which are changed, and any other files that are dependent on it. This saves a lot of time.

=> For a large project, when a few changes are made to the source, manually recompiling the entire project each time is tedious, error-prone and time-consuming.

Here is nice link for it :[How to write first makefile](http://www.firmcodes.com/linux/write-first-makefile-c-source-code-linux-tutorial/)

Answer (score 5):

A makefile is a recipe for computers with instructions how to perform certain tasks and with dependencies between those tasks.

In the simple form, it looks like so:

```
a.out: filename.c
        gcc filename.c
```

Read: "To build `a.out` from `filename.c`, run the command `gcc filename.c`. If `a.out` is newer than `filename.c`, then don't do anything"

Note: The first character in the `gcc` line **must** be a tab (Makefiles are whitespace sensitive)

Comment: ... and the program will be compiled ( build) using simple "make"  not "gcc filename.c"

Comment: this looks like the simplest makefile. Canit be simpler ?