# How do I use 'make' in C in case of a filename which contains a space?

Tags: c, makefile, terminal, clang

**Introduction:** I made a file called **temperature 2.c** and when I use the terminal to ‘make’ the file, it returns an error:
 `make: *** No rule to make target 'temperature 2'.  Stop.`

[Terminal output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkXGV.png)

This is what I type into the terminal window.

`make temperature\ 2` 

**Version Information:** I'm using macOS 10.12.5 with **Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)**
Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)

**Additional Information:** I've tried using `make "temperature 2"` as someone suggested that it works on Windows but it's not working on Mac.
I have selected the correct directory in the terminal window and I'm able to compile all other files flawlessly.

[Screenshot of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITyW1.png) 
I'm aware of the fact that I can simply replace the *space* with an *underscore* to fix the issue but I want to know why this is happening in the first place. 
Terminal works fine handling other directories which have a *space* in their name (using a backslash), so why isn't it working in this case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the relevat lines from your make file. I.e. make a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004278/allow-space-in-target-of-gcc-makefile

Comment: From the screenshot you don't have a Makefile, so what are you `make`ing?

Comment: @teroi It's not a duplicate. I tried looking it up before posting the question. This question hasn't been asked before

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn't use a make file. I simply used the 'make' command.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I never use a make file. I just use the 'make' command and it automates the script to make an executable, which I then run using ./filename

Comment: That's not how `make` works. Did it work in the past? For example, does it work if you rename the file to `temperature_2.c` and then do `make temperature_2`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, it works for all other files, and it also works if I change the name to temperature_2. The only problem is the 'space'. ps: I learned this method to 'make' files in CS50 course - Harvard's Introduction to Computer Science.

Comment: I didn't know this, you always learn something

Comment: Ah, no makefile. That means you are relying on make's implicit rules. It means it might work on some platforms and not on others.

Comment: @teroi That is exactly what happened. It worked on a windows machine but it isn't working on Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make feeds the commands to a shell that executes them as commands.  If you have one line like this:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

when you try to do

```
make "some thing".o
```

it will try to find a file called "some thing.c" and will execute

```
cc  -c -o some thing.o some thing.c
```

which is to try to compile to some the three files `thing.o`, `some` and `thing.c`

But if you change the rule to

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o "$@" "$<"
```

it will feed the shell with this

```
cc  -c -o "some thing.o" "some thing.c"
```

that will produce the correct behaviour.

## Makefile

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o "$@" "$<"
```

## Sample run (in a FreeBSD system):

```
$ make "the problem.o"
cc -O -pipe -c -o "the problem.o" "the problem.c"
```

Answer (score 5):

Make comes with several built in rules, but they won't be designed to cope with spaces or other "unusual" characters in the file names, so you'll need to write a Makefile that overrides them or change your filenames.

This rule is the one you're using - you have to put quotes around the target file `$@` and input file `$<`.

```
%: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my query. Although I've added another answer that uses a part of your answer

Comment: Just one quote: The syntax you are posting is valid *only in GNU make*, which is not the make available in Mac OSX (it is the one derived from BSD make, I'm afraid)

Comment: Looking at your answer, I actually vaguely remember that syntax now that you mention it. Looks like GNU make still recognises it too :O

Answer (score 2):

When calling make, it requires you to have a Makefile, for quick and simple one file c program,

try

```
gcc -o "temperature 2" "temperature 2.c"
```

or

```
clang -o "temperature 2" "temperature 2.c"
```

Your make clearly tells you that with:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'temperature 2'.  Stop.
```

Comment: I'm not trying to use gcc or clang and then use ./a.out. I'm simply trying to use the 'make' command to get the result

Comment: I you want to use make on a *NIX system, you'll have to have a Makefile, to tell make what to do. see [How to write a Makefile to compile a simple C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548464/how-to-write-a-makefile-to-compile-a-simple-c-program)

Comment: I'd like to add that 'make' is working with all other files. It's also working if I change the name from 'temperature 2' to 'temperature_2'

Comment: "Now for your task, really there is no need for a Makefile, since make has built-in rules that know how to compile a simple program." - I found this at the link you posted. There is no need for a makefile for simple programs.

Comment: there is a need for Makefile, see also answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/4950584/chris-turner. make internal rules cannot handle spaces.  If you don't want to use a Makefile, remove the spaces from the filename.

Comment: yes, now I get it. If you want to use special characters, you have to use a makefile. But it's not always necessary to use a makefile if the filename has simple characters.